# Could a company specializing in social networking offer a "dealer free" gun transfer service?

Tags: united-states, oregon, firearms

This is a followup to [this question](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/83345/32568) about trading firearms between individuals in Oregon.

An answer says

> Apart from transfers to and from the government, you can freely transfer a firearm under subsection (4)c to a spouse, domestic partner, parent, stepparent, child, stepchild, sibling, grandparent, grandchild, aunt, uncle, first cousin, niece, nephew, or spouse or domestic partner any of the above. ... Not a friend, not a second cousin, not an ex-spouse, definitely not a stranger.

A comment points out

> So giving a gun to my second cousin wouldn't be allowed, but could I give it to my father who gives it to his cousin who gives it to his daughter, and thus it legally ends up with my second cousin anyway?

Could a social media company, given knowledge of personal relationships, offer a service for how to transfer firearms without a dealer, using the above "cousins all the way down" method? (Are there laws about avoiding this law?) Obviously this won't work for everyone, but for two relative strangers that have a long family history in the general vicinity it seems possible to work out.

Comment: For clarity ... [*"Transfer” means the delivery of a firearm from a transferor to a transferee, including, but not limited to, the sale, gift, loan or lease of the firearm."](https://oregon.public.law/statutes/ors_166.435)

Comment: It would require a chain of *still living* relatives, all cooperating. So this seems to be a theoretical option, lots of effort for very few cases.

Comment: Seems like it would be easier to be a domestic partner for a day…

Comment: I believe there are some federal laws around "straw purchases" of guns, but I'm not sure if they would apply here.  Maybe a place to start research.

Comment: One practical obstruction is that, since the legality would require every step to be a voluntary gift, the originally intended recipient has no legal recourse if someone along the chain decides to simply keep the gun for themselves.